# In Azure DevOps, how do I prevent build from failing if unit tests fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a build pipeline for simple .net project . There are some unit tests also which is failing . But I dont want the build job to fail and I want the artifacts to be published if unit tests are failing. How to achieve this.
I used ContinueOnError on the VStest Task. It dint publish artifacts and it doesnt show build job as passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding failTaskOnFailedTest on your task

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: false
```

Comment: no this dint work . it still shows build failed.